# How are aggregates instantiated to test other aggregates with?

Tags: unit-testing, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, axon

Suppose I have an aggregate that, for some operation, requires the existence of another aggregate. Let's assume I have a `car` and a `garage`. There might be a command called `ParkInGarage` that looks like this:

```
public class ParkInGarage {

    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    public final UUID carId;

    public final Garage garage;

    //... constructor omitted
}
```

I've [read](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/319808/312886) that to validate the existence of an aggregate, it is good practice to use the loaded aggregate in commands since that already implies its existence (as opposed to passing a `garageId`).

Now when unit-testing the `Car` using [Axon's fixtures](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/3.0/part-ii-domain-logic/testing), I can not simply instantiate my `Garage` by saying `new Garage(buildGarageCmd)`. It will say:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot request current Scope if none is active

Because no infrastructure was set up.
How would I test such a case, or should I design the aggregate differently?

### Abstracted, real-world example

The aggregate root I am working with may have a reference to itself to form a tree-structure of said aggregate root. Let's call it `Node`.

```
@Aggregate
public class Node {
    private Node parentNode;
}
```

Upon creation, I can pass an `Optional<Node>` as parent, or set the parent at a later time using a separate command. Whether the parent should be defined as instance or by ID is part of the question.

```
public class AttachNodeCmd {
    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    public final UUID nodeId;
    public final Optional<Node> parentNode;
}
```

In the command handler, I need to check if attaching the node to given parent would introduce a cycle (the structure is supposed to be a tree, not a common graph).

```
@CommandHandler
public Node(AttachNodeCmd command) {
    if (command.parentNode.isPresent()) {
        Node currentNode = command.parentNode.get();
        while (currentNode != null) {
            if (currentNode.equals(this)) throw new RecursionException();
            currentNode = currentNode.parentNode.orElse(null);
        }
    }

    //Accept the command by applying() an Event
}
```

At some point, the parent needs to be instantiated to perform those checks. This could either be done by supplying the aggregate instance in the command (discouraged), or by supplying a `Repository<Node>` and the `nodeId` to the command handler, which is the aggregate itself and also discouraged. Currently I don't see a right way to do this and further down the road a way to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @plalx is putting you on the right track. Commands are part of your API/Message Contract and exposing the Aggregate in there isn't that great an idea.
Additionally I'd like to note that the `AggregateFixtures` in Axon are there to test a single Aggregate, not the coordination of operations between Aggregates.

Coordination between aggregates/bounded contexts is typically where you see sagas coming in to play. Now to be honest, I am a bit in doubt whether this use case justifies a Saga, but I could imagine that if the `ParkCarInGarageCommand` fails because the `Garage` Aggregate is full (for example), that you need to instruct the `Car` Aggregate through another command telling it it's a no-go. The Saga set up in Axon might help you with this as you can easily catch (1) the exception from handling the command or (2) handle the event notifying the operation wasn't successful.

Comment: What aggregate would a `ParkCarInGarageCommand` be directed to? As far as I understand, sagas are only started by events. Thus something else will have to handle the command initially. How would that 'something else' get instances of whatever aggregates are required? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I have edited my post to provide a more concrete example of what I'm trying to do and test. It would be great if Axon could provide an example solution for this as currently I can't find any hint in the docs. I'm sure it is a common problem.

Comment: Also, if I can't have any aggregate(members) in commands or events, how do I reconstruct an aggregate root with object pointers to aggregate members with just the IDs? All these rules are incredibly restricting.

Comment: Any component/singleton/bean can have an `@CommandHandler` annotation on it. So you could add a separate singleton dealing with the `ParkCarInGarageCommand`, which in turn sends commands, for example.
If you'd want to use a Saga, then use, that should start on some events and in turn can publish commands to the Aggregates it is tied to. That would mean you'd have a different starting point of this operation, which I'd be hard pressed to tell you which it is as I am not familiar with your domain.

Comment: And lastly, Aggregate Members in Axon terms are the entities the Aggregate consists off. If you're event sourcing, those entities are created in an `@EventSourcingHandler` annotated function. Due to this, the Aggregate Members will be 'event sourced' on it's own, without you have to bother with this.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm getting the hang of it. The solution to the tree 'consistency boundary' is to introduce another entity that acts as aggregate root and protects the tree structure invariant. All operations are performed through it, such as adding nodes and linking them. In the event (sourcing) handler for adding nodes, new nodes are being instantiated right there. This eliminates the need for a repository or existence check.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't put AR instances in commands. Command schemas should be stable and easy to serialize/reserialize as they are message contracts.

What you could do instead is resolving the dependency in the command handler.

```
//ParkInGarage command handler
Garage garage = garageRepository.garageOfId(command.garageId);
Car car = carRepository.carOfId(command.carId);

car.parkIn(garage);
```

I don't know Axon Framework at all, but that should be relatively easy to test now.

Comment: That's a neat solution, however Axon doesn't let you inject repositories in command handlers and also discourages you from using repositories within aggregates, since loading takes time and increases the chances of concurrent modifications while the aggregate is locked. Your proposal makes a lot of sense, but I fear it's a more of a framework limitation in this case.

Comment: Seems like a weird framework limitation as resolving dependencies in command handlers/application services is an industry standard among DDD practitioners.